# Angular Element - "failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified"

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, angular-elements

I have an angular element (within an nx workspace). when i use it in another angular project I get TypeScript dependency errors.

It seems my elements cannot inherit any dependancies (or use peerDependancies) from its' host node_modules because of these errors.

The screenshot shows the errors caused by adding my angular element to another angular app.

> [image]../met-libs-nx/dist/libs/core/fesm2015/jomatech-core.mjs:7:0-47 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/fire/database' in '/Users/omar/Sites/met-libs-nx/dist/libs/core/fesm2015'
> Did you mean 'angular-fire-database.js'?
> BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@angular/fire/database' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
> (probably because the origin is a '*.mjs' file or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
> The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
> Add the extension to the request.

I assume i need to build my angular element (module) dependancies differently? What do you need to see?

the internet says updating [webpack config](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467) is the way to go but how do i do that in an angular env?

#### package.json

[image]

#### ng-package.json

[image]

#### tsconfig.lib.json

[image]

#### tsconfig.lib.prod.json

[image]

Comment: did you fix this problem? @Omar

Comment: @liangqicai im pretty sure that updating my angular project in the host app made the errors go away. With that in mind; building the libs without ivy probably woud be the correct way to solve this. Although i didnt test it